# Servlet not working after deployment in apache tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am new to JAVA development.

I have created a simple Servlet called 'test'.

```
package com.MyServlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   
    public test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();  
        pw.println("<h1>This is get request.</h1>");
    }

    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();  
        pw.println("<h1>This is post request.</h1>");
        
    }

}
```

its works in Eclipse with Apache Tomcat. But after deployment on Apache Tomcat, it gives the error *" error instantiating servlet class"*.

Version is Tomcat 9.0.54 on both server and eclipse PC.

The operating system Win 10 and also tired on win server 2016.

At First time when I run Servlet, it gives an error `Error instantiating servlet class [com.MyServlets.test]` 
here I have uploaded a full error screenshot
[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/BBNN4Sg)

And When I try to access the same servlet second time I get this `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists`. Here I have uploaded a full error screenshot [enter link description here](https://ibb.co/2PNV98p)

My other JSP page works properly on the same Apache Tomcat.

I tried [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)
It still has not worked

Comment: Which version of tomcat do you have in eclipse, and which one is it where it doesn't work? Also, can you provide more detailed error message, e.g. from the log?

Comment: e.g. if deployment doesn't work on Tomcat 10: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/64387472/13447

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. If similar Questions exist, explain how they do not address your issue.

Comment: Virson is Tomcat 9.0.54.

Comment: Version is Tomcat 9.0.54 on both server and eclipse PC. The operating system Win 10 and also tired on win server 2016.   At First time when I  run Servlet, it gives an error **Error instantiating servlet class [com.MyServlets.test]** here I have uploaded a full error screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/BBNN4Sg).   &   When I try to access the same servlet second time I get this **The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**  here I have uploaded a full error screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/2PNV98p).

Comment: Does [Tomcat - UnsupportedClassException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907015/11748454) answer your question?